# What devices use ath10k_hwmon-pci-1400 sensor chip?

Tags: linux, sensors

I've been trying to figure out what devices the specific sensor chip type ..._hwmon-pci-... is used for. In this case, say it's ath10k_hwmon-pci-140. I can't find this documented, I saw some references that it could be a wifi chip sensor, but on this system, it's not a wifi chip as far as I know. I had initially assumed it might be a type of gpu sensor, like amdgpu, nouveau, or radeon, but now I don't believe that assumption is correct, but I cannot find documentation that says what the hwmon class of sensor chips actually are used for and with. The other sensors are all roughly obvious, but the specific '..._hwmon-pci' type I cannot figure out. I read some of the kernel docs on various chip sensor vendors, but that did not really explain it to me either.

Note I am not asking about other sensor chips (like board, cpu, disktemp, nvme, gpu sensors, etc), I know what those do, and what they generally are associated with, I'm asking about the specific '..._hwmon-...' type sensor chips only.

```
k10temp-pci-00d3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +27.5°C  
Tdie:         +27.5°C  

ath10k_hwmon-pci-1400
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +50.0°C  

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +30.5°C  
Tdie:         +30.5°C  
Tccd1:        +28.5°C  
Tccd2:        +27.8°C  
Tccd3:        +28.8°C
```

If anyone can explain the types of devices these ..._hwmon chips are used in, that would be helpful, thanks.

In other words, in the above sample, what devices would it be likely that the ath10k_hwmon-pci-1400 sensor chip is referring to? I know it's not the cpu, or the internal cpu dies, and I do not believe this system even is using a monitor, so it's unlikely though not impossible that it's a gpu chip sensor for a non nvidia/amd/intel gpu. I also don't think it's a wifi device. But I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I just learned that the ath..._hwmon is in fact a wifi sensor, iwl..._hwmon.. are wifi device sensors.

- Sensor IDs starting with: 'ath' or 'iwl' means a wifi sensor, starting with 'eth' or 'enp' [and possibly 'eno'] means a LAN nic sensor.
- Sensor IDs starting with: radeon/amdgpu/nouveau/intel... are possible gpu sensors, not sure about the intel.
- Sensor IDs starting with drive[temp]/nvme: are disk/ssd/nvme sensors.
- The presence of the string 'hwmon' in the actual sensor chip ID 'may' indicate that it is a secondary, not systemboard, or cpu, sensor chip, but of course, all sensor chips are hardware monitors at some level, unless they are monitoring ambient temperatures.

Theoretically, reverse mapping the pci-busid from pci data back to sensors would yield the device type for pci bus devices, but not for other bus types.

Note that this does not answer the overall question, what types of devices can use a ..._hwmon-... chip, but it's a start. I believe a better way to have asked this question would be:

What types of sensor string IDs are associated with specific non systemboard/cpu sensors? Is the ..hwmon- a standard way to spot such sensors?